# What's the right material design library to use in my gradle, i've tried different solutions, it's not building successfully

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to test the FAB concept in my app but it's not working following the guidelines i got maybe because i didn't understand it well, see my gradle file below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "study.timmy.micah.materialdesignpractices"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso 
    core:3.0.2'

}
```

Comment: please share the error

Comment: `com.android.support:design` is correct, but you might not want an alpha version  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button